# Error When Using Maven to Compile Google Guava From Source Code

Tags: maven, guava

I have cloned the Google Guava Project (https://github.com/google/guava) to my local Mac computer

I ran **mvn validate** beforehand without any issues.

When running the command **mvn clean** and then **mvn package**, I ran into this error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) on project guava-tests: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure: [ERROR]
> /Users/MY_USERNAME/guava/guava-tests/benchmark/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FuturesGetCheckedBenchmark.java:[37,25]
> package java.security.acl does not exist
>
> The guava unit testing library ran correctly but the "guava unit
> tests" failed. I'm not sure why it's not working out of the box, and
> so I would love any recommendations for how to get the project
> working, even if it doesn't fix this particular error.
>
> I'm including the full error message below for reference (with -e
> flag)
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) on project guava-tests: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure: [ERROR]
> /Users/MY_USERNAME/guava/guava-tests/benchmark/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FuturesGetCheckedBenchmark.java:[37,25]
> package java.security.acl does not exist [ERROR]
> /Users/MY_USERNAME/guava/guava-tests/benchmark/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FuturesGetCheckedBenchmark.java:[96,11]
> cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class NotOwnerException [ERROR]
> location: class
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.FuturesGetCheckedBenchmark [ERROR]
> /Users/MY_USERNAME/guava/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/reflect/TypeTokenTest.java:[421,11]
> types java.lang.CharSequence and java.util.List are incompatible;
> [ERROR]   class
> java.lang.Object&java.util.List<java.lang.String>&java.lang.CharSequence
> inherits abstract and default for isEmpty() from types
> java.lang.CharSequence and java.util.List [ERROR]
> /Users/MY_USERNAME/guava/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/reflect/TypeTokenTest.java:[435,11]
> types java.lang.CharSequence and java.util.List are incompatible;
> [ERROR]   class
> java.lang.Object&java.util.List<java.lang.String>&java.lang.CharSequence
> inherits abstract and default for isEmpty() from types
> java.lang.CharSequence and java.util.List [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) on project guava-tests: Compilation failure
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by:
> org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:
> Compilation failure
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute (TestCompilerMojo.java:180)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Answer (score 1):

We don't have the Guava build working with newer versions of Java (like Java 17): https://github.com/google/guava/issues/5801